# Why are so many wave functions associated with hydrogen?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atoms, hydrogen

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Three-dimensional_examples), there's an infinite set of possible wavefunctions (orbitals) for the hydrogen atom:
$$\psi_{n\ell m}(r,\theta,\phi) = \sqrt {{\left (  \frac{2}{n a_0} \right )}^3\frac{(n-\ell-1)!}{2n[(n+\ell)!]} } e^{- r/na_0} \left(\frac{2r}{na_0}\right)^{\ell} L_{n-\ell-1}^{2\ell+1}\left(\frac{2r}{na_0}\right) \cdot Y_{\ell}^{m}(\theta, \phi )$$

1. Would an unperturbed electron ever go outside the lowest orbital?
2. At some point the perturbation (excitation) energy would exceed the ionization energy, so above that certain energy, no orbitals could ever be populated, so what's the point of having all these solutions?

[image: Probability densities for the first few hydrogen atom orbitals]
"Probability densities for the first few hydrogen atom orbitals" ([source](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1.Would an unperturbed electron ever go outside the lowest orbital?

First, there is no such thing as "outside the lowest orbital" because the lowest orbital has probability density at all points in space (no nodes).

But yes, at a given temperature electrons will be distributed amoung the energy levels in accordance with a Boltzmann distribution.

> 2.At some point the perturbation (excitation) energy would exceed the ionization energy, so above that certain energy, no orbitals could ever be populated, so what's the point of having all these solutions?

There are infinite solutions none of which exceed the ionization energy (the ionization energy is only approached as n approaches infinity).

Think of a series like 0, 3/4, 8/9, 15/16, etc. where there are infinite members without reaching 1 (1 is approached in the limit of infinity).

Comment: so if I have only one electron, which can be at all points in space via the lowest orbital, what additional information I get from all the other orbitals? especially since they completely change (hybridize etc.) when around other atoms.

Comment: @Sparkler although in the ground state the electron can be anywhere is space, each point has a probability density.  If the electron enters a higher energy state, the probability density will change.  For example, if the atom is in a 2s state instead of a 1s state, the electron has a greater probability of being further from the proton.

Comment: and is there any "use" of superposition of orbitals when discussing a single isolated atom?

Comment: "There are infinite solutions none of which exceed the ionisation energy" is not the whole story, strictly speaking. Technically, the solutions are not limited to such *bound states* which give rise to *discrete* energy spectrum, the are also infinite number of solutions all of which exceed the ionisation energy. These solutions correspond to *unbound states* and give rise to *continuous* part of energy spectrum.

Comment: See, for example, [here](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Textbook_Maps/General_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Lower's_Chem1/04._Atoms_and_the_Periodic_Table/The_Bohr_Atom#Spectrum_of_the_hydrogen_atom).

Comment: @Wildcat, right it's not the whole story, in addition to infinite discrete bound solutions there is a continuum of infinite unbound solutions; the whole story would need to include relativity, nuclear spin, electron spin etc. too.

Comment: @Sparkler a superposition of equal-energy wavefunctions will also be a solution to the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: i know superpositions can be used to approximate helium for example, but do these superpositions actually needed to represent an electron behaviour in an isolated hydrogen?